# Android custom camera - orientation issue

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, exif

I'm developing an app where I have to implement custom camera. I run into one issue.

I take a photo, save it and then upload it to the server using Retrofit 2.

I get the camera orientation like this:

```
private int getRotation(int id) {
    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(id, info);
    return info.orientation;
}
```

And this is working for preview - the preview orientation is OK.

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);
```

The rotation of the camera is set like this:

```
parameters.setRotation(rotation);
```

I checked the saved photo, and the orientation of the photo is OK.

I tested it on 3 devices - Huawei Y5 and Nexus 5X - the orientation of the saved and uploaded file to the server is ok. And now the weird pard - on 3rd phone Samsung Galaxy J5 is orientation of the saved file correct, BUT orientation of the uploaded file on the server is wrong. The saved photo has correct orientation, I can see it in File Manager in the phone, but the image that was uploaded to the server, has wrong orientation, no mater what rotation I set to the camera in the code.

Getting image from camera:

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // restart preview
            restartPreview();
            // save image to the file
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if(pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                uploadFile(pictureFile);
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                Logcat.d("FileNotFoundException");
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Logcat.d("IOException");
            }
        }
    };


private void uploadFile(File file) {
        AppName.getInstance().photo(mLastLocation, file, new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                Logcat.d("CapturingService uploadFile onResponse: " + response.raw());
                if(mCapture) {
                    // count delay to take another photo
                    .....
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,delay);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Logcat.d("CapturingService uploadFile onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "but the image that was uploaded to the server, has wrong orientation" -- what do you mean by this? There are two things that affect what a human sees in terms of the orientation of a photo: how the JPEG image itself is saved, and the `Orientation` EXIF header. Many Android camera units will always save the image in landscape, but use the EXIF header to tell image viewers to rotate the image. Not all image viewers will honor the EXIF header, and that header might be lost if the image gets converted along the way.

Comment: I mean that the image that is saved on the server is 90° rotated, but the same image that is saved in the device has correct orientation. And I force the activity to be in portrait and the photo is rotated as if it was captured on landscape.  So probably the EXIF orientation informations are missing? How I can fix it? I have suspicion that the problem can happen during the Retrofit2 upload.

Comment: "So probably the EXIF orientation informations are missing?" -- since I did not understand the first two sentences of your previous comment, I cannot answer that. Use something like `exiftool` to dump the EXIF headers of both the image that you saved on the device (that you manually copy off to your development machine) and the image that is on your server, and see if there are differences in the `Orientation` header.

Comment: Um, that photo shows up as portrait for me, in Firefox 45 on Linux. Compute their MD5 hashes or something to confirm that the files are indeed identical. They should be, unless something is doing image processing along the way.

Comment: Oh I see now. The problem is only when I use html to display the image `<img src="/img/Photos/_1459709212.jpg">` If I go directly to the URL of the image, the image rotation is correct.